# Sequelize is setting PSQL to VARCHAR(255) regardless if I tell it TEXT(2048) or any other length

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When I follow the instructions on how to create a larger field in psql through sequelize, it still always pushes `VARCHAR(255)` when it creates the table. [Sequelize Data Types](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#data-types)

Here's my sequelize model:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Message = sequelize.define(
    'Message',
    {
      message: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(2048),
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      }
    },
    {}
  );
  Message.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Message;
};
```

`DataTypes.TEXT` has the same result.

Here's the SQL that it outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Messages" ("id" SERIAL , "message" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
```

When I try to insert a large string (more than 255 characters) into this field, it gives me the following error:

`error: value too long for type character varying(255)`

I've tried the following github issues on the project, but they don't seem to work for me. [Relevant github issues.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=error%3A%20value%20too%20long%20for%20type%20character%20varying%28255%29)

Thank you for any help.

**Specs:**

psql (PostgreSQL) `10.5`

node `v10.4.0`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "pg": "^7.5.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.39.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a mistake when I changed this datatype in my model. I forgot to make the same change to my migration file which was key. I'm glad it was this simple.

tl;dr

Make sure your migrations have the same datatype as your model.